# adding users to ADGroupMember with userPrincipalName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to add a group of users to ad group having only userPrincipalName.

```
Import-Csv "C:\Temp\TESTGroup.csv" | %{ Add-ADGroupMember "Group Name" $_.userprincipalname}
```

This results in an error message relating to `$_.userprincipalname`

I want to add a group of about 65 people to this AD Group.

Comment: Please add the full error log otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `-Members` parameter of `Add-ADGroupMember` requires an identifier that is not UserPrincipalName. So you need to query for another identifier based on UserPrincipalName in this case. Since `-Members` accepts an array of ADPrincipals, you can update the membership with one command.

```
$UPNs = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\TESTGroup.csv"
$UIDs = Foreach ($UPN in $UPNs.userprincipalname) {
    (Get-Aduser -filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $UPN}).SamAccountName
}
Add-ADGroupMember "Group Name" -Members $UIDs
```

Comment: that work, thank you so much 

I have done it with samaccountname in the past but this time was only giving the email address and was trying to make it work on the UPN

Thanks again

Comment: Virtually everybody uses SamAccountName@Domain for UPN. It would be a whole lot faster to do `$UIDs = $UPNs.userprincipalname -replace '@.*'` rather than run `Get-ADUser` against each person.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I have to respectfully disagree with the comment that everyone uses that naming scheme. For older on-premise AD environments, they probably started that way. But if they then adopted a hybrid Office 365 sync, they would have had to update UPN to be email address. In that same scenario, their AD domain may not have been publicly routable either, which could have resulted in a different domain name for the UPN. Thus potentially having a difference. I do not believe that is an uncommon occurrence. But if that is the case, then you are correct about it being much more performant.

Comment: @Ace, thanks for the update. If your SamAccountName match the string preceding the @ in the UPN data, then you can apply TheMadTechnicians suggestion and make this code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> The Members parameter specifies the new members to add to a group. You
>   can identify a new member by its distinguished name (DN), GUID,
>   security identifier (SID) or SAM account name. You can also specify
>   user, computer, and group object variables, such as
>   `$<localUserObject>`. If you are specifying more than one new member,
>   use a comma-separated list. You cannot pass user, computer, or group
>   objects through the pipeline to this cmdlet. To add user, computer, or
>   group objects to a group by using the pipeline, use the
>   `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet.

So you need one of the accepted formats:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\TESTGroup.csv |
  % { Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userprincipalname)'" } |
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Group Name' -Members { $_.sAMAccountName }
```